# Value of optional type CGFloat not unwrapped error in Swift

Tags: swift

Code:

```
var loadView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.window?.frame.size.width, self.window?.frame.size.height))
```

I try to create a UIView progrmatically.when try to set window height and width for view it gives error as "Value of optional type 'CGFloat?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?"
why this error showing?any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are using [optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-XID_356), which means that `self.window?.frame.width` evaluates to a valid integer if `window` is not `nil`, otherwise it evaluates to `nil` - same for `height`.

Since you cannot make a `CGRect` containing `nil` (or better said, `CGRectMake` doesn't accept an optional for any of its arguments), the compiler reports that as an error.

The solution is to implicitly unwrap `self.window`:

```
    var loadView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.window!.frame.size.width, self.window!.frame.size.height))
```

But that raises a runtime error in the event that `self.window` is `nil`. It's always a better practice to surround that with a optional binding:

```
if let window = self.window {
    var loadView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, window.frame.size.width, window.frame.size.height))
    .... do something with loadVIew
}
```

so that you are sure the view is created only if `self.window` is actually not nil.