# Swift - NSURL error

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

Getting an error when trying to use the `NSURL` class below, the code below is essentially trying to store an image I am pulling in from Facebook into an `imageView`. The error is as follows:

```
value of optional type 'NSURL?' not unwrapped, did you mean to use '!' or '?'
```

Not sure why this is is happening, help!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myImage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myProfilePictureURL = NSURL(string: "http://graph.facebook.com/bobdylan/picture")
        let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: myProfilePictureURL)
        self.myImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually the compiler tells you exactly what to do.

Comment: Just do `NSData(contentsOfURL: myProfilePictureURL!)` `!` in the end.

Comment: As @MartinR said you need to silence this warning by clicking on the Red Warning, press Enter and build it.

Comment: I don't want to sound rude, but if you want to program in Swift then you *have to* understand what optionals are and what unwrapping means. You should also be able to lookup the docs to see that `NSURL(string:)` returns an optional. There are also many similar questions (with answers) on SO already.

Comment: Thanks for the help Martin, I am still a newb at Swift.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Value of optional type CGFloat not unwrapped error in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662595/value-of-optional-type-cgfloat-not-unwrapped-error-in-swift)

Comment: Martin, in the future don't say "I don't want to sound rude" and then you won't sound rude.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **NSURL** constructor you're calling has got this signature:

```
convenience init?(string URLString: String)
```

**?** means that the constructor may not return a value, hence it is considered as an **optional**.

Same goes for the **NSData** constructor:

```
init?(contentsOfURL url: NSURL)
```

A quick fix is:

```
let myProfilePictureURL = NSURL(string: "http://graph.facebook.com/bobdylan/picture")
let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: myProfilePictureURL!)
self.myImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
```

The best solution is to check (unwrap) those optionals, even if you're sure that they contain a value!

You can find more infos on optionals here: [link to official Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_496).

Comment: Thank you Matteo, appreciate the help here. It runs fine now.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, the compiler tells you exactly what to do, and Xcode offers a fix-it to, uh, fix it.

Here's the *why*: `NSData`'s `init(contentsOfURL:)` initializer takes a non-optional `NSURL` reference. That means you're not allowed to initialize a data object by passing `nil` instead of a URL — doing so would be nonsensical. (If you really want to create an empty `NSData`, use an initializer that's more semantically appropriate for doing that.) It also means you can't pass a reference that has the *possibility* of being nil — that is, an [optional](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_496).

When you receive an optional, you need to check and unwrap it before passing to code that wants a non-optional reference. (See the aforelinked part of *The Swift Programming Language* for all the ways you can do that.) Doing this limits the number of failure points in your code — instead of having code several layers deep behind an API call breaking because you passed it something you didn't expect to, Swift pushes you to catch unexpected values before they get to be a problem.